# Implement a tool guide feature for the canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

I'm challenging my self by attempting to code a semi functional graphic design program using the canvas element. The issue I'm having is trying to find a way show guides when using one of the tools.

For example, if the user is using the line tool I'd like for them to see a dashed line while dragging the mouse and then add the line to the canvas when the mouse is released. Then if they click to add another line the guide should work without clearing the rest of the canvas. Here's a snippet from my LineTool class. I'm aware that currently it clears the entire canvas during the mousemove event.

I think I would instead need to add another canvas for the guides on top of the canvas that's being drawn on while displaying the guides. Then when the mouse is released switch back to the drawing canvas, but this approach feels overcomplicated. Is there any better approach?

I'd appreciate any good resources on the anatomy of the code behind graphic design programs. Now that I'm thinking about it I almost feel like every individual line, shape, or even path should be on its own separate canvas.

```js
  #mouseMoveHandler(event) {
    if (this.isMouseHeld && this.active) {
      if (this.showToolGuide) {
        this.endAnchor.x += event.movementX;
        this.endAnchor.y -= event.movementY;
        this.activeCanvas.clear();
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.activeCanvas.stroke = "#fff";
        this.ctx.setLineDash([5, 10]);
        this.activeCanvas.line(this.startAnchor, this.endAnchor);
      }
    }
  }

  #mouseDownHandler(event) {
    let startAnchor = {
      x: event.offsetX - this.activeCanvas.cx,
      y: (event.offsetY - this.activeCanvas.cy) * -1,
    };
    this.#requestPointerLock();
    this.startAnchor = startAnchor;
    this.endAnchor = { ...startAnchor };
    this.showToolGuide = true;
    this.isMouseHeld = true;
  }

  #mouseUpHandler(event) {
    if (this.showToolGuide) {
      let dx = this.endAnchor.x - this.startAnchor.x;
      let dy = this.endAnchor.y - this.startAnchor.y;
      this.ctx.clearRect(this.startAnchor.x, this.startAnchor.y, dx, dy);
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.activeCanvas.stroke = "#fff";
      this.ctx.setLineDash([]);
      this.activeCanvas.line(this.startAnchor, this.endAnchor);
      this.showToolGuide = false;
    }
    this.isMouseHeld = false;
    document.exitPointerLock();
  }

  #mouseDown = this.#mouseDownHandler.bind(this);
  #mouseUp = this.#mouseUpHandler.bind(this);
  #mouseMove = this.#mouseMoveHandler.bind(this);

  init(canvas) {
    this.activeCanvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = this.activeCanvas.ctx;
    this.activeCanvas.elm.addEventListener("mousedown", this.#mouseDown);
    this.activeCanvas.elm.addEventListener("mousemove", this.#mouseMove);
    this.activeCanvas.elm.addEventListener("mouseup", this.#mouseUp);
  }

  destroy() {
    this.activeCanvas = null;
    this.ctx = null;
    this.activeCanvas.elm.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.#mouseDown);
    this.activeCanvas.elm.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.#mouseMove);
    this.activeCanvas.elm.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.#mouseUp);
  }
```

Comment: You need to keep track of all shapes on your canvas in the memory of your program. Then, when something changes, you redraw ALL shapes. That's how canvas works. It can be a pain, but there are libraries that fix this problem for you. PIXI.JS keeps track of  all objects individually and can move / delete individual objects on a canvas.